# how to write the path in ckeditor?

Tags: php, javascript

I have installed ckeditor, and I am using the KCFinder plugin as the upload image tool. http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/docs/integrate#session.

Now I don't know how to make the path right. my ckeditor's path is `test/ckeditor....`
the kcfinder's path is `test/kcfinder...`

How do I write this code?

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
```

Is the above path right? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have said I would have a **guess**

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/test/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
```

Comment: my guess would be `'../kcfinder/browse.php?type=files'`.

Comment: It is a URL though and not a path.

Comment: Would be a relative URL in my case.
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Absolute_vs_relative_URLs)

Comment: :) Thanks for the link - not sure I could have figured it out without that! ;) I know the difference. I prefer absolute URIs in config files like this. Anyway this discussion is pointless as it all just stabbing in the dark given the question.